# Xcode/Swift Code-Folding

Tags: swift, xcode, code-folding

I know I can fold blocks by pressing `command + option + left arrow`

But the problem is when I'm trying to fold a block of lazy codes.

Example:

```
private lazy var linePass: UIView = {
        let line = UIView()
        line.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return line
    }()
```

But It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. This is fixed in Xcode 10 beta 3.